# Bluetooth earbuds not playing any sound after a while while video calling on my macbook

Tags: macos, audio, video, bluetooth, macbook

I am using a 2017 MacBook air. I can watch videos with the same earbuds without any issue at all for however long. But, when video calling or attending meetings in WhatsApp and MS Teams (haven't tried in any other apps), I can listen and speak with the earbuds, everything's fine, but after a while, nor I can hear any sound neither I can speak. It would still be connected to the computer.

If I disconnect and connect my BT earbuds, I can again hear the sounds. It will happen again after a while. The problem is only when I use Bluetooth Earbuds, no problems at all when I use wired ones.

I can't seem to figure out what could be the problem. Tried the usual, restart, forget and re-pair, different earbuds, etc. Disconnecting and reconnecting it seems to temporarily fixes it. My BT earbuds don't have any problem with calls and meeting on my android tablet and phone.